# Supertokens - get userid by user email

Tags: authorization, user-management

Using supertokens (hosted), is there a direct way to query the userId of another user by email? The only solution I found was to fetch all users and search for it, which is obviously not efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the recipe and the SDK you use, there are functions available for that. For example, with the NodeJS SDK, you have:

#### EmailPassword recipe

[`getUserByEmail`](https://supertokens.com/docs/nodejs/modules/recipe_emailpassword.html#getUserByEmail-1)

#### ThirdParty recipe

[`getUsersByEmail`](https://supertokens.com/docs/nodejs/modules/recipe_thirdparty.html#getUsersByEmail-1) (notice that this will return an array of users since you can have multiple users sign up with the same email, but different OAuth providers)

#### Passwordless recipe

[`getUserByEmail`](https://supertokens.com/docs/nodejs/modules/recipe_passwordless.html#getUserByEmail-1) (This function will return `Promise<undefined>` if the user doesn't exist, if if they had used phone number to sign up)

#### ThirdPartyEmailPassword

[`getUsersByEmail`](https://supertokens.com/docs/nodejs/modules/recipe_thirdpartyemailpassword.html#getUsersByEmail-1)

#### ThirdPartyPasswordless

[`getUsersByEmail`](https://supertokens.com/docs/nodejs/modules/recipe_thirdpartypasswordless.html#getUsersByEmail-1)

### Other SDKs

For other backend SDKs, you can check out their docs:

- [Python SDK](https://supertokens.com/docs/python/recipe/index.html) -> choose your recipe -> choose either `asyncio` or `syncio` module (depending on your web framework execution env) and then you will see a list of functions exposed by that recipe. One of them will allow you to get the user from their email.
- [Golang SDK](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/supertokens/supertokens-golang#section-directories) -> click on the "recipe" item, choose your recipe, and you will see a list of functions exposed by that recipe. One of them will allow you to get the user from their email.

### Using the SuperTokens Core APIs directly

In the [API Spec](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/supertokens/CDI/2.13.0), you can see sections for each recipe. Depending on how the user signed up, you can query that `/recipe/user` GET API with their email as a query param. Be sure to pass in the correct `rid` header in the GET request.